# PHP drop down list from db, view selected post and UPDATE post

Tags: php, mysql

Hi  I would like to have it to work with two fields, both id and text but I cant even get this to work.

I get a post from the database to update. 
If I have a ordinary optionlist. It views the selected value and I can change option and save it to the database.

This works:

```html
<select name="ddlLinkType" title="<?php echo $row_visa_link['LinkType']; ?>">
                
          
          <option value="" <?php if (!empty($row_visa_link['LinkType']) && $row_visa_link['LinkType'] == '' ) echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>></option>
  <option value="Styrelsen" <?php if (!empty($row_visa_link['LinkType']) && $row_visa_link['LinkType'] == 'Styrelsen')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Styrelsen</option>
  <option value="Alla" <?php if (!empty($row_visa_link['LinkType']) && $row_visa_link['LinkType'] == 'Alla')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Alla</option>
  <option value="Option3" <?php if (!empty($row_visa_link['LinkType']) && $row_visa_link['LinkType'] == 'Option3')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Option3</option>

          
        </select>
```

But I would like to get the options dynamic from database table. I have tried  many things now but nothing works. I am so confused and everything is messed up right now. I am trying to generate the optionlist without loosing the function that it shows the selected value from the post  to be updated.

This doesnt work:

```html
<select name="ddlLinkCategory" title="<?php echo $row['LinkCatID']; ?>">
          
       <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCategoy)) { ?>
          
      <!-- Dont know how to solve this-->
       
       <option value="<?php($row['LinkCatID'])?>" <?php if (!empty($row_visa_link['LinkCategory']) && $row_visa_link['LinkCategory'] == $row['LinkCatID'])  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>$row['LinkCatID']</option>
        
  
         <?php }}  ?> 
        </select>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Double curly brackets at the end?

Comment: Never saw this before `<?php(...)?>` to echo something

Comment: Why don't you just limit the query to 1 and use that value?

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong:

```
<select name="ddlLinkCategory" title="<?php echo $row['LinkCatID']; ?>">

   <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCategoy)) { ?>
```

You dont acces to `<?php echo $row['LinkCatID']; ?>` in line 1, $row is defined in line 2.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You! Now it Works :)

```html
<select name="ddlLinkCategory" title="<?php echo $row_visa_link['LinkCategory']; ?>">
          
   <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCategory)) { ?>
          
   <option value= "<?php echo($row['LinkCatID'])?>"<?php if (!empty($row_visa_link['LinkCategory']) && $row_visa_link['LinkCategory'] == $row['LinkCatID'])  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>> <?php echo $row['LinkCatID']?></option>
        
 <?php }}  ?>  
 </select>
```